# Linux, code that checks there are no currently running cron jobs?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cron, process-management

How would I write a bash script that checks there are no currently running cron jobs,  then does some simple action?

I am not talking about cron jobs that are scheduled to run at some point,  I am referring to actively running processes.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very interesting question.  I don't have an answer, but a suggestion:  can you run through the `ps` list, and look to see if the parent is cron pid, or does cron clean the parent of administratively started processes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

intresting question ;)

```
for pid in `pgrep cron`;do
  ps uh --ppid $pid;
done|grep -v CRON
```

Comment: Thanks, how does this work?   I am not sure of the structure of cron processes -- actually looks like it doesn't quite work, looks like CROND might start the processes?

Comment: all jobs which are run by cron are started from a forked process created by cron. the above iterates thru all processes which have forked by cron (pgrep cron), and for all these pids lists these processes childrens

Answer (score 0):

You can read the crontab like this

```
crontab -l | grep -v "^#" | awk '{print $6}'
```

and check if any of the script/job is running